# How to trigger email from a google sheet (which is collecting data being a web hook) as and when a new row is added?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, webhooks, email

I am using google sheets web app as web hook to capture customer checkout information. My payment gateway is [instamojo](http://instamojo.com).

I am able to capture checkout information onto the google sheet.(used code some thing similar to the one [here](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/mhawksey/1276293/raw/5a0090f4f1c976a5273bc3ec3622551420f1e701/gistfile1.js)

Now, I would like to send an email to every customer who check-out from my store. I wrote a google script sendEMail() which is working fine when I run the code.

How can I trigger this function as and when the webhook captures a new customer data (which is added as a new row on google sheet).

I tried using triggers where event source is "spread sheet " and all possible event types ( "On open","On edit", "On Change" and "On form Submit").

Nothing seems to trigger the sendEmail() function. There is nothing wrong in sendEmail() function anyway. Its woking when I run it manually.

// my code is [here](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/mhawksey/1276293/raw/5a0090f4f1c976a5273bc3ec3622551420f1e701/gistfile1.js) which pulled from GitHub // and working fine as web hook and capturing checkout information

// I added sendEmail() code as below

```
function sendEmail() {
    ....
    ....
    MailApp.sendEmail("mail-id@domain.ext", "subject line", "mail message"); 
}
```

// Now, I am unable to build/plug a trigger to fire sendEMail() function. Pls help.

I don't see any error messages.

I expected the trigger to fire sendEmail function as and when a new row is added. But that's not happening.

Comment: "Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. " [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers). Why not try a time-driven trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried time driven trigger and its working. I feel that's not the effective way. Will you please explain a bit more on installable triggers?

Comment: There are [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Installable "offer more flexibility..." For you, this includes an additional type of event - time-driven triggers. Your code adds a new row to a given sheet-the basic triggers ("onEdit" and "onChange") are NOT triggered because "Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run". You can't use onFormSubmit because your input isn't submitted by a form. That leaves "time-driven".

Comment: Why can't you use the same webhook code to trigger `sendEmail`?  Just send a POST to the same URL and have `doPost` call `sendEmail`.

Comment: Hello  dwmorrin,  Thanks a lot for the reply. Will you please provide an example on sending POST to the same url?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Within your web hook and `capturing checkout information code`, you
>   are using at some point the method

```
row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
```

### I assume that your headers contain the information you need to send your email.

For example, if the information you want to include into the subject line of your email is contained in headers[3], just append within your webhook code the function

```
MailApp.sendEmail("mail-id@domain.ext", headers[3], "mail message");
```

before you close your `for` loop:

```
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
MailApp.sendEmail("mail-id@domain.ext", headers[3], "mail message"); 
    }
```

**Another example:** if the whole row is meant to be the body of the email, write:

```
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
MailApp.sendEmail("mail-id@domain.ext", "subject line", row);
```

### The email will be sent every time the customer checkout information is updated.